# Is there a way to read certain columns of every row in excel?

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

first of all, I am very new to C#.
I would like to select every row of my excel sheet and put it in a text doc. The problem is, that I only need certain columns(21 out of 70+).

Here is my code:

For example:

```
Excel:
 |1  2  3  4  5
1|x  y  c  v  b
2|x  y  c  v  b
3|x  y  c  v  b
```

And I need every row 1 to 3 but only the data from column 2,3,5

In my text doc I want it to like like:
y c b
y c b
y c b
But atm it looks like:
y
y
y
c
c
c
b
b
b

```
int[] spalten = new int[] { 5, 22, 24, 27, 29, 32, 34, 37, 39, 43, 45, 48, 50, 54, 56, 59, 61, 65, 67, 71, 73 };
for (int x = 0; x <= 20; x++)
{
  //loop all columns 
  for (int j = 4; j <= 74; j++)
  {
    //loop all rows
    for (int i = 5; worksheet.Cells[i, 5].Value != null; i++)
    {
      //add the cell data to the List
      if (j == spalten[x])
     {
         if (worksheet.Cells[i, j].Value == null)
         {
           Console.WriteLine("leer");
           string Inhalt = "leer" + "\t";
           string[] lines = { Inhalt };

           File.AppendAllLines(Path.Combine(docPath, "Daten2.txt"), lines);
        }
      else
      {
       excelData.Add(worksheet.Cells[i, j].Value.ToString());
       Console.WriteLine(worksheet.Cells[i, j].Value);
       string Inhalt = worksheet.Cells[i, j].Value.ToString()+"\t";
       string[] lines = { Inhalt };
       File.AppendAllLines(Path.Combine(docPath, "Daten2.txt"), lines);                                      
      }          
     }
   }

}


 }
```

Comment: Excel works with cell ranges. Even the `Cells` property is a Range. You can specify ranges using address strings just as you would in Excel, or by specifying the starting/ending rows and columns

Comment: There is a discrepency in what you are asking. It appears that you are already able to read the columns you need; your question is about outputting the values to a textdoc, is that correct? You are asking how to output the data in the correct order?

Comment: @AndyG thats right. I can read the cells and write them into a text doc. But I dont know how to arrange right. It seems like my code goes form column to column and not from row to row. I used "https://riptutorial.com/epplus/example/26603/import-data-from-excel-file" as a basis

Comment: No time for a full answer, but here are some hints: loop over the rows first, then take the columns of this row and concatenate them into a single text line, which you output to your text file. Also, you can loop over only the configured columns by doing something like this: `foreach(int j in spalten) { /*... */ }` - this removes the need for the  `for (int x = 0; x <= 20; x++)` loop and the `if (j == spalten[x])` check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the order of your loops: loop over the rows first, then over the columns for the current row. Inside the inner loop, concatenate the column values into a single string.

For performance reasons, try to do as little work as possible inside the loop (e.g. do not access `worksheet.Cells[]` twice with the same indices). Use [`StringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=netframework-4.7.2) to concatenate strings. You can use [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in) to loop over the configured columns only.

```
var configuredColumns = new int[] { 5, 22, 24, 27, 29, 32, 34, 37, 39, 43, 45, 48, 50, 54, 56, 59, 61, 65, 67, 71, 73 };   

// loop over all data rows (ignore first 5 rows which are headers)
// stop looping if the current row has no data in column 5
var allRowTexts = new List<string>();
for (int row = 5; worksheet.Cells[row, 5].Value != null; row++) {

    // loop over the configured columns
    var rowText = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var col in configuredColumns) {

        var cell = worksheet.Cells[row, col];
        if (cell.Value == null) {
            rowText.Append("leer" + "\t");
        }
        else {
            rowText.Append(cell.Value.ToString() + "\t");                
        } 
    }

    // rowText now contains all column values for the current row
    allRowTexts.Add(rowText.ToString());
}

// write all rows into file
File.AppendAllLines(Path.Combine(docPath, "Daten2.txt"), allRowTexts);
```

[C# Fiddle using dummy WorkSheet and Console output](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FDSuFT)

Comment: It worked almost perfectly except I now have some kind of pyramid in my Textdoc.

Comment: Got it. I tooke the "allRowTexts.Add(rowText.ToString());" out of the for Loop. Thank you very much

Comment: Yeah I had the `allRowTexts.Add()` in the wrong place originally, it must happen after the inner loop finishes. Glad I could help you.

Comment: I have a small Question. Most of my exceldata are in the DD/MM/YYYY format but not all. In my text doc they appear as DD/MM/YYYY 00:00:00. Is there a way to chop the time part?

Comment: I think this might be worth its own question. The idea is to check if the cell is of `DateTime` type (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37534183/1450855), depends on correct formatting of the source excel), get this value as DateTime, then format it with with a [custom format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings), e.g. `dateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")`